# Move box around parent div

Tags: javascript, html, parent

I have an assignment where I have to create two boxes, one inside of the other. The smaller(inside) box is supposed to be able to move freely with a mousedrag inside of the container box. The smaller box is not supposed to be able to leave the larger box. I have figured out the first part(moving the box) but can't quite figure out the second? I'm sure I'm just overlooking something simple, so any tips would be appreciated. This is my code.

```
window.onload = init;
var mousePiece = null;

function init() {
    var box = document.getElementById("box");
    container = document.getElementById("container");

    box.style.top = getStyle(box,"top");
    box.style.left = getStyle(box,"left");
    box.style.height = getStyle(box,"height");
    box.style.width = getStyle(box,"width");

    container.style.top = getStyle(container,"top");
    container.style.left = getStyle(container,"left");
    container.style.height = getStyle(container,"height");
    container.style.width = getStyle(container,"width");


    addEvent(box, "mousedown", mouseGrab, false);
}

function mouseGrab(e) {
    var evt = e || window.event;
    mousePiece = evt.target || evt.srcElement;

    addEvent(document, "mousemove", mouseMove, false);
    addEvent(document, "mouseup", mouseDrop, false);
}

function mouseMove(e) {
    var evt = e || window.event;
    var mouseX = evt.clientX;
    var mouseY = evt.clientY;

        mousePiece.style.left = mouseX - 25 + "px";
        mousePiece.style.top = mouseY - 25 + "px";
}

function mouseDrop(e) {
    mousePiece = null;
    removeEvent(document, "mousemove", mouseMove, false);
    removeEvent(document, "mouseup", mouseDrop, false);
}

function addEvent(object, evName, fnName, cap) {
    if (object.attachEvent)
        object.attachEvent("on" + evName, fnName);
    else if (object.addEventListener)
        object.addEventListener(evName, fnName, cap);
}

function removeEvent(object, evName, fnName, cap) {
    if (object.detachEvent)
        object.detachEvent("on" + evName, fnName);
    else if (object.removeEventListener)
        object.removeEventListener(evName, fnName, cap);
}

function getStyle(object, styleName) {
    if (window.getComputedStyle) {
        return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(object, null).getPropertyValue(styleName);
    } else if (object.currentStyle) {
        return object.currentStyle[styleName]
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Jesse.

Answer (score 0):

In your `mousemove` function you must test to see if the new position falls outside of the container, and if it does change the values before assigning it to the box.

See http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/eutk9u48/

---

Explanation of fiddle

Inside the `init` function we fill an object named `limit` (*which is declared at the top*) with the left/top/right/bottom positions of the container (*for easy reference*)

```
// parseInt is used to get the numbers without the 'px' at the end
// so we can perform numeric comparisons with it
limits.top = parseInt(container.style.top); 
limits.left = parseInt(container.style.left);
limits.right = limits.left + parseInt(container.style.width);
limits.bottom = limits.top + parseInt(container.style.height);
```

Then in the `mousemove` method we do

```
var newX = mouseX - 25; // store the new X position based on mouse
var newY = mouseY - 25; // store the new Y position based on mouse

// make sure the newX does not go past the right side of the container
// by keeping whichever is smaller 
// if the newX we got from the mouse is larger than the right side of the container
// then we force the newX to become equal to the right side.
newX = Math.min(newX, limits.right); 

// The same principle applies to the left side but we now need to keep the larger value
// of newX or the left side of the container
newX = Math.max(newX, limits.left);

// same logic for top/bottom 
newY = Math.min(newY, limits.bottom);
newY = Math.max(newY, limits.top);
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly how this works?

    newX = Math.min(newX, limits.right - 50);
    newX = Math.max(newX, limits.left);
    newY = Math.min(newY, limits.bottom - 50);
    newY = Math.max(newY, limits.top);

Comment: @Jesse, added some code and comments in my answer (*the 50 is just the size of the box*), remove it and see what happens.

Comment: Okay, that seemed to work in firefox seems like it isn't working in chrome which is the browser my professor marks in. I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: @Jesse, that is because chrome will return `auto` (*from the `getComputedStyle` call*) as the value of the top/left of the container. You will have to give a `top:0;left:0;` to the `#container` css rule. See http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/eutk9u48/1/
 keep in mind that you will often come by such issues and that is the cross browser compatibility hell we have to deal with. Libraries like jQuery help a lot with giving a stable API to work with..

Comment: Oh perfect, that worked. That's so weird that chrome does that. At any rate, thank you for your help :)

Comment: I'm having a second problem on the second part of the question. The larger box is still supposed to act as a container for the smaller box, but when you move the smaller box to the edge of the larger box and keep going, the larger box is supposed to move with it. To clarify, the small box can drag the large box.

    if(newX >= limits.right - parseInt(getStyle(mousePiece,"width"))){
        container.style.left = newX + parseInt(getStyle(mousePiece,"width")) - parseInt(getStyle(container,"width"))+"px";
    }

Is my added code.